# PHP: Run shell command with piping the password

Tags: php, command-line-interface, exec, shell-exec

I need to run this command to open a mac encrypted image, I have forgot the password and want to brute force is with code.

Just to check if my code is working, I created a new image to check it. It does not work.

```
$command = "echo -n Secure@3@1| hdiutil attach -stdinpass Hidden.dmg"

// I have tried exec, shell_exec, popen like
exec($command);

// Every time it returns `hdiutil: attach failed - Authentication error`
```

Can someone please suggest what wrong with the code, as I have verified from shell itself the password is correct and command works.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer with proc_open, Leaving here for future references.

Copied this function from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#94929.

```
function my_exec($cmd, $input='')
{
    $proc=proc_open($cmd, array(0=>array('pipe', 'r'), 1=>array('pipe', 'w'), 2=>array('pipe', 'w')), $pipes);

    fwrite($pipes[0], $input);fclose($pipes[0]);
    $stdout=stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr=stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);fclose($pipes[2]);
    $rtn=proc_close($proc);
    return array('stdout'=>$stdout,
               'stderr'=>$stderr,
               'return'=>$rtn
          );
}

my_exec('hdiutil attach -stdinpass Hidden.dmg', 'Secure@3@1'); // Worked
```

Calling this function worked without using pipe.

> Still looking for answer why pipe operator does not work.

Comment: Hi I'm trying to do three pipe, is it possible with this function , I don't see any output I want the process work on the background .